# EPSG:3857 : find approximate distance between points with PyQGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, distance, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to calculate the distance between 2 points with different methods, eg QgsDistanceArea(), trigonometry `((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**(1/2)` I always get the same result, nearly 150% of the real value. Now I understand this is due to the project's CRS, EPSG:3857, and I can't find any easy method in these forums.

Yet when I use the manual rule on the map and set the method on Ellipsoidal instead of Cartesian I can measure the distances on the map quite accurately ? At least precisely enough for what I need, ~ 1%.

Using PyQGIS, is there a way to get the same values as the QGIS rule ? starting from points coordinates (x1, y1), (x2, y2), units in meters or lat/long degrees, whichever the simplest ?

If not, I'm wondering about using a factor like `t = cos(Lat°)`, or similar approximation ?

Comment: Web Mercator is hopelessly bad at distance measurements. That is not its purpose. You **cannot** get useful distance or area measurements in 3857. Just use an appropriate projection.

Comment: I tried other projections first (even before I encountered this issue) but the plugin I'm using as a base didn't let me do it. I'm not sure what was the issue exactly, only that 3857 works fine...

Comment: The issue is that only one dimension changes, so your "approximation" is a partial differential equation.